# How can I prevent Angular2 from wrapping a component in a DOM element?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I would like to manipulate an `<SVG>` element within an Angular2 project.  I would like to create various svg elements within the main `<SVG>` tag at runtime.  I have read the tutorial on dynamic component creation on angular.io (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html), and I have it basically working.  But it seems like Angular wraps each component in its own DOM element, named after either the component's selector, or a simple DIV with a class/id named after the selector.  So when I insert an element, I get output that looks like the following:

```
<svg id="logo" style="border: 3px solid black" viewBox="0 0 600 400" width="600" height="400">
    <svgcirclecomponent>
        <circle r="100" cx="10" cy="10"></circle>
    </svgcirclecomponent>
</svg>
```

What I would LIKE to have is the following:

```
<svg id="logo" style="border: 3px solid black" viewBox="0 0 600 400" width="600" height="400">
    <circle r="100" cx="10" cy="10"></circle>
</svg>
```

However I cannot simply hard-code the `<circle>` in the parent SVG component, since I need to create and manipulate multiple types of inner components.  Is this possible in Angular2?

Here is my code.  If I've left something out let me know and I'll add it.

## svg.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, Output, ViewEncapsulation, ViewChild, ComponentFactoryResolver } from '@angular/core';
import {MdButton} from '@angular/material';
import {SvgChildItem} from './svgChildComponents/svgChildItem';
import {SvgChildDirective} from './svgChildComponents/svgChild.directive';
import {SvgChildComponent} from './svgChildComponents/svgChild.component';
import {SvgCircleComponent} from './svgChildComponents/svgCircle.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'svgCanvasComponent',
  template: `
    <button md-button (click)="addNewComponent()">Add Circly</button><br />
    <svg width="800" height="800" viewBox="0 0 800 800">
        <template svg-child-host></template>
    </svg>
  `
})
export class SvgCanvasComponent  {
    @ViewChild(SvgChildDirective) svgChildHost: SvgChildDirective;

    constructor(private _componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

    addNewComponent() {
        console.log('adding circly');
        let svgChildItem = new SvgChildItem(SvgCircleComponent, {"x":10, "y":20});
        let cmpFact = this._componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(svgChildItem.component);
        let viewContainerRef = this.svgChildHost.viewContainerRef;
        let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(cmpFact);
        (<SvgChildComponent>componentRef.instance).data = svgChildItem.data;
    }
}
```

## SvgCircle.component.ts

```
import {Component, Input, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import {NnpUtilModule} from '../../nnpUtil.module';

import {SvgChildComponent} from './svgChild.component';

@Component({
    selector: "svgCircleComponent"
    ,template: `
        <svg:circle [attr.cx]="x" [attr.cy]="y" r="100">
    `
    ,encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class SvgCircleComponent implements SvgChildComponent {
    @Input() x: number;
    @Input() y: number;

    @Input() data: any;  //  from SvgChildComponent interface

    constructor() {
        //[this.x, this.y] = [Math.random(), Math.random()];
        [this.x, this.y] = [10, 10];
        //console.log(NnpUtilModule.getFive());  //  TODO: load this from a service so everyone can share the util?
        console.log('constructing SvgCircleComponent');
    }
}
```

## SvgChild.component.ts

```
export interface SvgChildComponent {
    //  common interface to standardize the api for passing data to the SVG components
    data: any;
}
```

## SvgChildItem.ts

```
import {Type} from '@angular/core';

export class SvgChildItem {
    constructor(public component: Type<any>, public data: any) {}
}
```

## svgChild.directive.ts

```
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[svg-child-host]',
})
export class SvgChildDirective {
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
}
```

Comment: You could use `'svg'` as the selector for your own component to avoid the additional element, just like Angular does to override native `<form>` tags. Or you could use a directive instead of a component, i.e. `<svg circle>` where `circle` is the name of your directive.

Comment: @AngularFrance:  I'm not sure I understand - I currently have two components: `<svgCanvasComponent>` (which has the real `<SVG>` tag in its template, and `<svgCircleComponent>` (which contains the `<svg:circle>` element I would like to insert/manipulate.  Which of these are you recommending that I change selector to `svg`?  Thanks!

Comment: Use the technique wherever you want to "skip" the additional DOM element. From your initial code it looks like it's `svgCircleComponent`.

Comment: Okay, I will attempt that.  So in this case, the selector for my `SvgCircleComponent` would become `<circle>`.  Where can I set my attributes in this case?  Seems like my template would be empty (since I would be using the selector itself to generate my main element).

Comment: If you use a `@Component` to match `<circle>`, then you'd have to include the `<circle>` tag again in your component's template (and I'm assuming all the original tag's attributes would have to become @Inputs in your component). However, if you use a `@Directive` to match `<circle>`, it will leave the original markup untouched, and you'll be in a good position to add behavior to or change properties of the original element, like [ngForm](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/forms/src/directives/ng_form.ts#L60) does.

Comment: Could you please explain the rationale behind encapsulating `<circle>` in a component? (i.e. Why can't you use the raw element directly? Do you need to dynamically generate additional markup / alter the existing markup / add behavior...?)

Comment: @AngularFrance: Aah, okay.  So I may need to investigate using a directive instead of a component.  I will do that.  Thanks a bunch for your help!

Comment: @AngularFrance: Regarding the rationality behind encapsulating `<circle>`:  Quite possibly because I don't know what I am doing.  ;-)  I would love to just use raw markup, but I was interested in letting Angular handle my event passing/variable binding, so that it is consistent with the rest of the app I am building.  Maybe that's not so good of a choice?

Comment: Hehe. You might be trying to reinvent HTML but in a way this is what Angular does with components, so why not. :) I'm really not familiar with the `<svg>` element and I'm probably a poor advisor on that topic. But if you do find yourself spitting out the same markup again and again in your pages (be it `<svg>` tags or any other markup), it certainly makes sense to encapsulate it in a component to avoid repeating yourself.

Comment: @AngularFrance: My end goal is to have various "widgets" built with SVG, out of svg snippets, so I'm really liking the templating nature of Angular.  For now it seems dumb because I'm only doing a single `<circle>`, but later it will get more complicated.  Hoping to get it working in this simple case first.  Per your suggestion, I tried using same `circle` in both selector AND in template, but that caused an infinite loop, because it was trying to construct a circle in a circle (in a circle in a circle in a ...)  :-).  I'll have a look at directives now.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Anytime. Next time, don't hesitate to create a Plunkr so we can play with your code.